# OS X: Redirect error output of command to environment variable

Tags: macos, shell-script

I know that I can redirect the stdout to an environment variable, e.g.

```
retcode=$(/usr/bin/osascript -e 'do shell script ... with administrator privileges')
```

but how do redirect the stderr output to an environment variable, too (in this example to detect a user cancelling the admin credentials dialog)?

Answer (score 1):

This is the most simple way to redirect stdout and stderr into one variable:

```
output=$(/usr/bin/osascript -e 'do shell script ... with administrator privileges' 2>&1)
retcode=$?
```

It's getting more complicated, if you want to catch stdout and stderr separately. I think the only straight-forward way is to redirect stdout/stderr to separate files:

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e 'do shell script ... with administrator privileges' >/tmp/$$.stdout 2>/tmp/$$.stderr

retcode=$?
output=$(cat /tmp/$$.stdout)
stderr=$(cat /tmp/$$.stderr)
```

Make sure you clean up the files later.